# Tuning Spark Job

Tags: performance, apache-spark, transformation, shuffle

I'm trying to tune the process below, because I'm having a very `Java heap space error.`

Looking at the Spark UI, there is a `cogroup` that behaves in a very strange way.
Before that stage, everything seems balanced very well( at the moment I have hardcoded number of partitions,48). Inside the method `loadParentMPoint` there is the cogroup trasformation and basically when I'm going to execute the next count, the cogroup is calculated and basically 48 tasks are scheduled, but 47 of them terminate immediately(seems doensn't have nothing to process), except one that start doing **shuffling read**, until it fill up heap space and exception is raised.

I have launched few times the process with the same data set and the end is always the same. **Everytime It works just one executors., while before is well balanced.**

**Why I'm having this behavior?** **Maybe I'm missing anything?** I tried to `repartition` data before cogroup,  because I supposed it was unbalanced, but it doesn't works, the same when I tried to use `partitionBy`.

**This is the code excerpt:**

```
    class BillingOrderGeneratorProcess extends SparkApplicationErrorHandler {

    implicit val ctx = sc
    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[BillingOrderGeneratorProcess])
    val ipc = new Handler[ConsumptionComputationBigDataIPC]
    val billingOrderDao = new Handler[BillingOrderDao]
    val mPointDao = new Handler[MeasurementPointDAO]
    val billingOrderBDao = new Handler[BillingOrderBDAO]
    val ccmDiscardBdao = new Handler[CCMDiscardBDAO]
    val ccmService = new Handler[ConsumptionComputationBillingService]
    val registry = new Handler[IncrementalRegistryTableData]
    val podTimeZoneHelper = new Handler[PodDateTimeUtils]
    val billingPodStatusDao = new Handler[BillingPodStatusBDAO]
    val config = new Handler[PropertyManager]
    val paramFacade = new Handler[ConsumptionParameterFacade]
    val consumptionMethods = new Handler[ConsumptionMethods]
    val partitions = config.get.defaultPartitions()
    val appName = sc.appName
    val appId = sc.applicationId
    val now = new DateTime

    val extracted = ctx.accumulator(0l, "Extracted from planning")
    val generated = ctx.accumulator(0l, "Billing orders generated")
    val discarded = ctx.accumulator(0l, "Billing orders discarded")

    // initialize staging
    val staging = new TxStagingTable(config.get().billingOrderGeneratorStagingArea())
    staging.prepareReading

    val rddExtractedFromPlanning = staging
        .read[ExtractedPO]()
        .repartition(48)
        .setName("rddExtractedFromPlanning")
        .cache 

    val rddExtracted = rddExtractedFromPlanning
      .filter { x =>
        extracted += 1
        (x.getExtracted == EExtractedType.EXTRACTED ||
         x.getExtracted == EExtractedType.EXTRACTED_BY_USER ||
         x.getExtracted == EExtractedType.EXTRACTED_BY_TDC)
      }
      .map { x =>
        log.info("1:extracted>{}", x)
        val bo = MapperUtil.mapExtractedPOtoBO(x)
        bo
      }

    val podWithExtractedAndLastBillingOrderPO = rddExtracted.map { e =>
      val billOrdr = CCMIDGenerator.newIdentifier(CCMIDGenerator.Context.GENERATOR, e.getPod, e.getCycle(), e.getExtractionDate())
      val last = billingOrderDao.get.getLastByPodExcludedActual(e.getPod, billOrdr)
      log.info("2:last Billing order>{}", last);
      (e.getPod, e, last)
    }
      .setName("podWithExtractedAndLastBillingOrderPO")
      .cache()

    val podWithExtractedAndLastBillingOrder = podWithExtractedAndLastBillingOrderPO.map(e => (e._1, (e._2, MapperUtil.mapBillingOrderPOtoBO(e._3))))

    val  rddRegistryFactoryKeys = podWithExtractedAndLastBillingOrderPO
      .map(e => (e._1,1))
      .reduceByKey(_+_)
      .keys

    val rddRegistryFactory = registry.get().createIncrementalRegistryFromPods(rddRegistryFactoryKeys, List())

    val rddExtractedWithMPoint = ConsumptionComputationUtil
      .groupPodWithMPoint(podWithExtractedAndLastBillingOrder, rddRegistryFactory)
      .filter{ e =>
        val mPoint = e._3
        val condition = mPoint != null
        condition match {
          case false => log.error("MPoint is NULL for POD -> " + e._1)
          case true =>
        }
        condition
      }
      .setName("rddExtractedWithMPoint")
      .cache

    rddExtractedWithMPoint.count

    val rddExtractedWithMPointWithParent = ConsumptionComputationUtil
      .groupWithParent(rddExtractedWithMPoint)
      .map{
        case (pod, extracted, measurementPoint, billOrder, parentMpointId, factory) =>
          if (!parentMpointId.isEmpty) {
            val mPointParent = mPointDao.get.findByMPoint(parentMpointId.get)
            log.info("2.1:parentMpoin>Mpoint=" + parentMpointId + " parent for pod -> " + pod)
            (pod, extracted, measurementPoint, billOrder, mPointParent.getPod, factory)
          } else {
            log.info("2.1:parentMpoin>Mpoint=null parent for pod -> " + pod)
            (pod, extracted, measurementPoint, billOrder, null, factory)
          }
      }
        .setName("rddExtractedWithMPointWithParent")
        .cache()

    rddExtractedWithMPointWithParent.count

    val rddRegistryFactoryParentKeys = rddExtractedWithMPointWithParent
      .filter(e => Option(e._5).isDefined)
      .map(e => (e._5,1))
      .reduceByKey(_+_)
      .keys

    rddRegistryFactoryParentKeys.count

    val rddRegistryFactoryParent = registry.get().createIncrementalRegistryFromPods(rddRegistryFactoryParentKeys, List())

    rddRegistryFactoryParent.count

    val imprb = new Handler[IncrementalMeasurementPointRegistryBuilder]

    val rddNew = rddExtractedWithMPointWithParent.map({
      case (pod, extracted, measurementPoint, billingOrder, parentPod, factory) =>
        (parentPod, (pod, extracted, measurementPoint, billingOrder, factory))
    })
    rddNew.count

    val p = rddNew.cogroup(rddRegistryFactoryParent)
    p.count

    val rddExtractedWithMPointWithMpointParent = p.filter{ case (pod, (inputs, mpFactories)) => inputs.nonEmpty }
    .flatMap{ case (pod, (inputs, mpFactories)) =>
        val factory = mpFactories.headOption //eventually one or none factory
        val results = inputs.map{e =>
          val measurementPointTupla = factory.flatMap{f =>
            Option(imprb.get.buildSparkDecorator(new MeasurementPointFactoryAdapter(f)).getMeasurementPointByDate(e._2.getRequestDate), f)
         }
          val tupla = measurementPointTupla.getOrElse(null)
          val toBeBilled = if(tupla!=null && tupla._1!=null) false else true
          val m = if(tupla!=null && tupla._1!=null) tupla._1 else null
          val f = if(tupla!=null && tupla._2!=null) tupla._2 else null
          (e._1, e._2, e._3, e._4, m, toBeBilled, e._5 , f)
        }
      results
    }
    .setName("rddExtractedWithMPointWithMpointParent")
    .cache()

    rddExtractedWithMPointWithMpointParent.foreach({ e =>
      log.info("2.2:parentMpoint>MpointComplete=" + e._5 + " parent for pod -> " + e._1)
    })
}
```

These are the stages for the two RDDs involved into the cogroup operation, **rddNew:**

[image]

**rddRegistryFactory:**

[image]

**and this is the stage of the cogroup:**

[image]

**this is the storage situation:**

[image]

**this is the executors tabs:**

[image]

**N.B. I  added count action Just for debugging purpose.**

**UPDATE:**

- I tried to removed cache adn launch the process again, now each executor has around 100M used for storing data, but the behaviour is the same: shuffle read happens just for one executors.
- I tried also to do a join operation between the same two RDDs before the cogroup, just for to know if the problem I'm having is related to the cogroup only or is extended to all wide transformations and also for the join, the behaviour has been exactly the same.

Comment: seems like your `cache` is creating memory pressure. Why cache is required here? have you tried with out cache ?

Comment: I've added two more images, representing storage and executors situation. Maybe yes there is a little bit of heap pressure, but the behaviour is strange, can this caused just by caching abuse?

Comment: there are various factors not one, pls remove cache and see

Comment: I removed cache and launched the process again, I will let you know.Anyway that true, caching should be used judiciously, but actually this behaviour from my point of view, is not correct. The process could be slower, because of the useless cache, but why do shuffle read from just one executors? It doesn't have sense

Comment: Also, `count` is an action, why count is used many times?  are you using some where (I cant see usage of `count` in your code) ? if it is just for debug purpose you can use `countApprox()`. If its testing purpose you can remove it as well

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above, I have used count many times just for force computing all RDDs in order to see situation of the two RDDs involved into the cogroup operation, and see if unbalacing was caused by one of them, but before cogroup partitions seems distribute well. Ok I will use countApprox, thanks, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was related about `partitioning`. Basically data into the rdd calling `cogroup` operation had all keys at the same value, so when cogroup happens, Spark tried to hash partitioning both RDDs bringing keys of both rdd on the same executor in order to cogroup them.

Comment: Basically the problem was not the cogroup itself, but at the moment cogroup being executed, data was completely unpartitioned, actually I discover a bug causing all data come into the same partition, so fixing has been simply fixing the data going into the cogroup.

Comment: @Giorgio, Hi I'm facing memory issue while using `cogroup` any suggestions and tips would be great-full, as I'm new to spark and don't know how to resolve it. Please find the question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets]

Answer (score 2):

- I strongly believe this `Java heap space error` is because of cached rdds which seems like not necessary based on your last screen shot that is Storage tab.

[image]

Depending on how many times the dataset is accessed and the amount of work involved in doing so, re-computation can be faster than the price paid by the increased memory pressure.

It should go without saying that if you only read a dataset once there is no point in caching it, it will actually make your job slower.

- For counting for debug purpose you can use `countApprox()` instead of `count`. once testing is done you can remove it for real usage of your job
- most important thing is make sure that your data is uniform across by printing number of records per partition... If needed you can repartition and coalesce.

  can get the number of records per partition like this :

```
df
  .rdd
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex{case (i,rows) => Iterator((i,rows.size))}
  .toDF("partition_number","number_of_records")
  .show
```

Comment: I ran it, but the behaviour is the same, is doing shuffle read from just one executors. Now executors have storage free (just around 100M used each). Any other suggestion?

Comment: Yes, is coming exactly the same as before, please look at the post, I've updated it with the next tests I did

Comment: pls check [When Shuffles Don’t Happen](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/)

Comment: No other tips or ideas?